# Angular app compiling correctly, but it is not loading

Tags: angular

I'm building an app with Angular 6, and now I want to serve it using ExpressJS.

For this, I went on to compile the app using `ng serve --prod`, but the app was not loading, as I was getting `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in the console.

I thought that maybe something was wrong with my app, but it was working fine with `ng serve`, so I tried with `ng serve --prod`, and everything worked flawlessly still.

Then I decided to try with just `ng build` (no `--prod`), and got the same error.

In GitHub issues I found some related stuff, but were specific to some packages and older versions of angular.

This is my package.json, in case it is relevant:

```
{
  "name": "mt",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

I suposse the problem is not with my code per se, as the app is working fine with the `ng serve` command, with or without the `--prod` flag.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

EDIT: This is my express file to serve the app

```
const html = __dirname + '/dist/';
const port = 4200;
// Express
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app
    .use(compression())
    .use(bodyParser.json())
    // Static content
    .use(express.static(html))
    // Start server
    .listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Port: ' + port);
        console.log('Html: ' + html);
    });
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./dist/mtloops-web-app/index.html');
});
```

Comment: The problem is probably in how you *serve* the application. Tell us precisely how you do that.

Comment: Added an edit with the file in which I'm serving the app with Express

Comment: I don't know much about express, but my guess is that html should be `__dirname + '/dist/mtloops-web-app/'`.

Comment: That didn't work. The express server is "serving" the app correctly, the problem is the app is not loading and throwing the `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in console. When the server doesn't recognize the `index.html` file it throws an error on screen saying the file was not found.

Comment: which probably means that your server sends an HTML file when the browser requests a JS file. Look at your network panel in the dev tools to see what requests are made and what responses are received.

Comment: Thanks! that actually helped me! The problem was in `const html = __dirname + '/dist/';` (express file) and it should've been `const html = __dirname + '/dist/mtloops-web-app/';`. Because of that, when the server looked for the JS files, it couldn't find them and just sent the `index.html` file and thus the error.

Comment: Err, that's **exactly** what I told you 23 hours ago. And you said it didn't work.